# Is there a way for my build.gradle to pull from the project repository (possibly prompting the user to input for the passphrase)

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am currently creating a gradle build script. The whole purpose of the script is to encrypt files. Updates from this files will come from a repository (meaning every run on my script will be a version of encrypted files). In line with this when the script is run, it needs to pull updates from the repository first. My problem is, in console, when i do the pull command, it asks for a passphrase. However, I don't know how to implement this in the gradle build script. Is there a way to prompt the user for a password first and pass it to a git command in the script? I'm just new in this so I really need your help. thanks! :)

I have tried the Exec task which executes git pull (see code below).
I have also searched for other ways such as using config credential.helper cache but my references showed that it needs to do a git push (which prompts for password) first, for it to be stored in the cache.

```
task pullFromRepo(type: Exec) {
  commandLine "git", "pull"
  doLast {
    println "done pulling from repository"
  }
}
```

I expect a possible user prompt for the passphrase(?) retrieve this user input and pass it as argument in the git pull command. is that possible? thank you!! :)